# How to add and Persist a new ClaimsIdentity with custom claims to a ClaimsPrincipal after authentication by an OpenId Connect provider

Tags: authentication, cookies, asp.net-core, openid-connect

I'm using OpenId Connect with .NetCore to send users to an external OpenId Connect authentication provider (OP) which returns relevant access tokens and an authenticated ClaimsPrinciple which has claims from the OP in such as Name, Email Address, Customer Id, etc. What I want to be able to do is once the User has been authenticated and the ClaimsPrinciple is returned from the OP, I would like to add a ClaimsIdentities with custom claims for each licence the user holds on there account to the ClaimsPrinciple. So when a user switches between their account licences I can access the correct identity for that licence and provide access to features based on the custom claims. Currently, I can add the custom claims to a ClaimsIdentity then add the ClaimsIdentity to the ClaimsPrinciple but the new identities are not persisted and added into the Cookie.

So A User can have multiple licences.
For each licence I want to add a ClaimsIdentity.
Then I want to persist the changes to the ClaimsPrinciple by using a cookie.

Here is a code snippet which will hopefully add some context. This is for the Login method in my application which is hit once the OP has authenticated the user.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
     string token = HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token").Result;
     string refreshToken = HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token").Result;

     // ControllerBase User class this is the User I want to add the identites to, I think.
     string userGuid = User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "Guid").FirstOrDefault().Value;

      UserTokens userTokens = new UserTokens
      {
          LastUpdatedDate = DateTime.Now,
          UserGuid = userGuid,
          UserAccessToken = token,
          RefreshToken = refreshToken
      };

      await _busClient.PublishAsync<UpdateUserTokens>(new UpdateUserTokens(userTokens));

      // Domain Model User, a different User to the controllerBase User 
      // this is how a user is represented in my application but this has 
      // no control over authentication and claims
      User user = await _requestClient.RequestAsync<UserGuidRequest, User>(new UserGuidRequest(userGuid));
      var userLicences = await _requestClient.RequestAsync<UserLicenceRequest, List<UserLicence>>(new UserLicenceRequest(userGuid));

      var identityServerUserClaims = User.Claims.ToList();

      foreach(UserLicence userLicence in userLicences)
      {
          List<Claim> userLicenceIdentityClaims = new List<Claim>();
          foreach (Claim claim in identityServerUserClaims)
          {
              userLicenceIdentityClaims.Add(claim);
          }

          userLicenceIdentityClaims.Add(new Claim(userLicence.RoleType.ToString(), ""));

          var userLicenceIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(userLicenceIdentityClaims, User.Identity.AuthenticationType);

          userLicenceIdentity.Label = userLicence.Id.ToString();

          User.AddIdentity(userLicenceIdentity);
      }

      //TODO: either need to sign out then back in or save new user claims to cookies somehow?

      return View("Index", user);
 }
```

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more information please ask and I'll try to provide whatever I can, hopefully, this is a good start.